# Вопрос оптимизации JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, hikaricp

В процессе разработки приложения (сайта) на Java сервлетах, возник вопрос, который, возможно, покажется кому-то глупым, однако всё же.

По скольку резонно, что сайт использует подключение к БД (**Postgres** в моем случае), у меня появилось 2 вопроса об целесообразности использования пулов (таких как **Hikari**):

1. Для чего они вообще используется?
2. Какой тот самый подводный камень, не дающий использовать просто одно подключение к базе, которое не будет закрываться вообще никогда, пока приложение работает? С учетом что стейтменты и резалты закрывать не забываю

В чем минус второго подхода из-за чего стоит использовать пулы? Особенно, думаю не лишним будем отметить, что в приложении многопоточность используется довольно активно (даже если опустить момент, что сам по себе томкат мутит потоки)

Answer (score 2):

Пул соединений используется для того, чтобы решить несколько проблем, а именно:

1. открытия соединения с БД это небыстрая операция: в лучшем случае один вызов по сети (а то и больше), для некоторых СУБД (включая postgres) - старт процесса для обслуживания запросов и его инициализация. И это все еще до того, как приложение сможет выполнить собственно запрос к БД, ради которого все и затевается.
2. СУБД не могут эффективно одновременно обрабатывать слишком много запросов. Если одновременно приложение пошлет с десяток запросов, то суммарное время выполнения будет больше чем если бы приложение делало не более, скажем, 4 одновременно (эта степень возможности распараллеливания зависит от мощности сервера БД и типа запросов, которые посылают)

Как пул эти проблемы решает?

Первую проблему, он решает так, что соединения кешируются, т.е., когда приложение закрывает соединение, на самом деле оно не закрывается, а возвращается в пул, и когда приложение опять открывает соединение, то пул отдает уже готовое к работе соединение. И время такой операции на порядки ниже чем открытие соединения с нуля.

Вторую проблему пул решает таким образом, что он создает некое конфигурируемое максимальное число соединений. И если приложение пробует открыть новое, то такой вызов блокируется до тех пор, пока одно из соединений, которые используются, не будет возвращено.

Теперь, что касается вопроса об использовании одного соединения вообще на все приложение. Если так сделать, но нельзя будет параллельно выполнять запросы к БД. Есть определенные ограничения в JDBC (самое очевидное то, что транзакция БД привязана к соединению), плюс определенные ограничения конкретной реализации jdbc драйвера, протокола работы с БД и самой БД. Хотя JDBC спецификация и говорит, что класс `Connection` должен быть потоко-безопасный (и он такой и есть в postgres jdbc драйвере), и теоретически можно выполнять запросы используя одно соединение параллельно из разных потоков, на практике в постгрес это приведет к тому, что только один поток реально будет выполнять запросы, а другие будут ждать.

На практике это приведет к тому, что какой-нибудь медленный запрос, который инициирован одним пользователем заблокирует работу всех остальных.

И самое главное, что эти сложности совсем ни к чему. Модификация программы для использования пула соединений тривиальна, и решает эти проблемы раз и навсегда.

Comment: Тогда вопрос такой. А можно ли закрывать соединение не явно? Допустим:
У меня есть уже класс `SQLUtils` который может возвращать мне `ResultSet`, типа так:
 
`ResultSet rs = sqlUtils.getResultSet("SELECT * FROM %s", "tableName");` (там у меня `String.format`) по итогу мне прилетает ResultSet который я потом закрываю `rs.close()`, с ним же закрывается `PreparedStatement` через `statement.closeOnCompletion()`, а как закрыть так же подключение? Когда всё отработало. При этом не сильно перелопатив эти ютилсы

Comment: Кажется разобрался. Можно делать по идее `rs.getStatement().getConnection().close()`